# SharePoint List - Unable to Create a rule in Lookup column

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a SharePoint list with 22 columns. I would like to create a rule that sends an email each time one of the column values changes. So I went to the "Automate--> Create a rule menu"

It provides a list of columns on which I can set rules. The Date , Choice and free text columns are listed as options. However the lookup columns are not available for rule setting.

I need to create rules on the lookup columns. How do I do this?

Comment: I wasn't able to find a link to any official documentation but, according to this blog post by Ganesh Sanap, rules on `Lookup` columns are not currently supported: https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/27/rules-in-sharepoint-online-microsoft-lists/.

Answer (score 0):

As per my test, look up column is currently not supported by "Automate--> Create a rule". As an alternative, you can create a Power Automate to achieve your needs. Reference: [FLOW WHEN A SHAREPOINT COLUMN IS UPDATED](https://wonderlaura.com/2020/08/25/flow-when-a-sharepoint-column-is-updated/).